# ECMA Regex match everything till first occurrence of exact string

Tags: regex, ecma

I need a regex to to match the first occurrence of the `@endforeach` and not let last.

This is the Regex that I'm currently trying: `/(@(foreach|if)).*(@end\2)/`  The problem is it dose not stop matching till it gets to the last `@endforeach`

```
Model: ${Model.name}

Fields: [
@foreach (Model.fields as field)
@if ('${field.relationName}' === 'undefined')
    ${Model.name}.${field.name}
@endif
@endforeach
];

Relationships: [
@foreach (Model.fields as field)
@if ('${field.relationName}' !== 'undefined')
    ${Model.name}.${field.name}
@endif
@endforeach
];
```

Comment: Hello, what software does this question concern? Otherwise it should have been posted at StackOverflow. Also, I'd recommend reading on greediness of `*` and what `?` does as it'd likely get downvoted fast there.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/LgXaXI/1